# Redshift： Column defined as NOT NULL allows null data to load

Tags: amazon-redshift

I expected the columns defined not null, should prevent to load the null values.

But this time, we got several null data for the column defined not null and it loaded to table without any STL_LOAD_ERROR, like other tables.

That column places at the last column of the record.
And I'm wondering something wrong in the options of the copy command as follows.

```
ESCAPE
GZIP
DATEFORMAT 'auto'
TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
DELIMITER ',' 
ACCEPTINVCHARS '?' 
COMPUPDATE TRUE 
STATUPDATE TRUE
MAXERROR 0
TRUNCATECOLUMNS  
NULL AS '\000' 
EXPLICIT_IDS
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Aside from your question, using `auto` for date/time formats is a mistake.  Redshift will pick on a per-file basis, and it can vary the format it uses on a per-file basis.  You can end up loading some data as say DD/MM/YYYY and other as MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: I think you need to give the full COPY command, and also the DDL for the table.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting NULLs in the column?  Redshift allows for empty strings in character columns which aren't NULL

Comment: That could be it, Bill.  Well thought of!

Comment: @Max Ganz II Sorry for my late replay, but thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Bill Weiner Thanks, sorry for my late replay. That data contains both of empty '' and null.